# Delegation for NTLM and Kerberos

Tags: python, authentication, iis, kerberos, ntlm

I enabled Form Authentication in the IIS hosts my company website.
Then in one client script (Nodejs or Python) I tried to get some data from the website.

**Below is one Python example**:

```
import requests

# it will trigger NTLM Auth
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
session = requests.Session()
resp = session.get('http://test.com/test', auth=HttpNtlmAuth(r'.\local_account','password')) # If uses domain account and doesn't add any permission to the physical directory of the website, it returns 401 error
print(resp.status_code, resp.text)

# it actually trigger Kerberos Auth as the captured in the WireShark
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
session = requests.Session()
resp = session.get('http://test.com/test', auth=HttpNegotiateAuth())
```

**For NTLM Auth**, I need to create one local account and add it into the user list of the physical directory of the website (defaultly Windows grant read/read&execute/list folder access). Or if uses domain account, I need to add my domain account to the user list of the physical directory of the website.

**For Kerberos Auth**, I don't need to adjust the permission of the directory in the server.

**My questions are**:

1. for Kerberos Auth, it works without adjusting any permission. what is the reason? because of the delegation mechanism of Kerberos? If yes, it will have read or write or full control for the website directory? or the default access which only has read/read&execute/list folder? or same as IIS_IUSR?
2. why not add same delegation mechanism into NTLM? security concern or others? My opinions are if the authorization passes, that means the server will trust the client, why Kerberos implements the delegation but NTLM don't?

Many thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "delegation" when there is no two hops but one (your web server to `http://test.com`). About why `HttpNtlmAuth` requires some extra work, you need to dig into its code or ask its developers. For most technologies in the same setup (ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core for example), NTLM or Kerberos gives the same result (the request to `http://test.com` should pick the user credentials of the application pool identity). So either that Python package is buggy or you didn't use it the right way.

Comment: I remembered when you use delegate and domain name to access the website. IIS only use kerberos authentication and NTLM won't be allowed. And when you pass windows authentication, application pool identity will be used to executed these directories so no matter who pass the kerberos auth, you don't have to adjust permission.